# Why does LLVM have a vector type and an array type?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to understand why LLVM has the concept of a "vector type". Could LLVM have been designed without one and could vectorization/SIMD be implemented on top of the array type?

It seems to me that a `[8 x float]` could be mapped to a vector register in the same way as a `<8 x float>`.

Comment: I believe LLVM distinguishes between the two types because not all valid ArrayType element types are valid SIMD/vectorization VectorType element types.